# IdentityServer 4. Invalid operation Exception in MVC Client of IClientStore

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, identityserver4, .net-core-2.0

I am implementing an authentication Server with IdentityServer 4 in .net core 2 and to test it I have used this tutorial http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html
to implement an MVC client but it shows me this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.Stores.IClientStore' while attempting to activate 'IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator'.

I've tried a lot of things but none of them worked.

Thank you

This is Client MVC Side:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddIdentityServer();

        services.AddMvc();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
}
```

This is my startUp IdentityServer Side:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
                 .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                 .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                 .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                 .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                 .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

    }
namespace ClientMVC
```

{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });




    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

}

```
namespace Server
```

{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

```
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                 .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                 .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                 .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                 .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                 .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    { 
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add your startup.cs, in particular where you configure IdentityServer.

Comment: I added it in the post @RuardvanElburg

Comment: Hi was this issue solved for you

Answer (score 1):

In your MVC client configuration, that you have provided, remove:

> services.AddIdentityServer();

This should exist only in the startup of the Identity Server project. `services.AddAuthentication(options =>...` is the piece of code, that tells the MVC app, that it is protected by something, and further on, the `AddOpenIdConnect` specifies that this is your IdentityServer.

**EDIT**

In general all the services that you are using and *injecting* in your controllers, should be initially added in the `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`.

For example, if you have an 'IUserService' you need to add it to the IServiceCollection object. Like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
```

Comment: I did like you said @m3n7alsnak3 but i have this now : InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IdentityServer4.Services.IIdentityServerInteractionService' while attempting to activate '.Controllers.Home.HomeController'.

Comment: @aouselkadhi - Check the edit, and also I think that you have messed up the client and the server. Can you show more code from both of the `startup.cs` files? Better show the entire file (you can skip the usings of course :))

Comment: it s added like you said in the post :)

Comment: Don't add it to my answer - add it to your question

Comment: it s now added to my question.Thanks @m3n7alsnak3

Comment: What is happening in your HomeController? Are you injecting some things in it?